# How to pass arraylist to other function in AsyncTask..?

Tags: android

I am trying to pass an array list to other function in Asyctask but it is getting null.

Written following code to read an array list

```
@Override           
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (type) {
            case MZIP:      
                fileManager.createZipFolderForMulti(params[0]);             
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Written following code to pass an array list to AsyncTask

```
private void zipMiltiple(ArrayList<String> multiSelectData2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Back(MZIP).execute(multiSelectData2);
        Log.d("JWP", "METHOD :"+ multiSelectData2);
    }
```

Is there any issue in code?

Comment: you can make your asynctask an inner class of the activity. declare arraylist as a member of outer class and use the same in asynctask

Comment: Actually I have done same as you told.. but I getting null value in doInbackground() methos.

Comment: your arraylist might be null as Sajmon suggested below

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to pass the array list to the other function in Asyctask
>   but I'm getting array list null..

You need to check whether on this line:

```
private void zipMiltiple(ArrayList<String> multiSelectData2)
```

*multiSelectData2* variable is properly instantiated, i.e.

```
if (multiSelectData2 != null) {
   new Back(MZIP).execute(multiSelectData2);
   Log.d("JWP", "METHOD :"+ multiSelectData2);
}
else {
   // ArrayList is NULL
}
```

You need to make sure that your ArrayList is not `NULL`. You're passing ArrayList correctly but probably you are passing ArrayList that is not instantiated.

If it still won't work, problem is elsewhere and you should add here your logcat.

---

It's worth to say that there are more possible approaches:

- Pass `ArrayList` via constructor
- Make `AsyncTask` implementation inner class of Activity class `->` since
  this, you'll have direct access to variables in Activity

Comment: is this function right fileManager.createZipFolderForMulti(params[0]);

Comment: @vikasjagdale yes, its correct. but problem may be in method. check method's body.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to use inner class:

- put your function inside the inner class.
- implement `doInBackground`.
- call your function from `doInBackground`.

  package com.stack.question;

  ```
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.MotionEvent;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.RatingBar;
  import android.widget.RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener;

  public class StackActivity extends Activity {

      RatingBar ratingBar;
      float nowValue;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
          new yourclass().execute("99");
      }

      class yourclass extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<String>> {

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
              super.onPostExecute(result);
              yourfunction(result);
                          zipMiltiple(result);
          }

                  private void zipMiltiple(ArrayList<String> multiSelectData2) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          new Back(MZIP).execute(multiSelectData2);
          Log.d("JWP", "METHOD :"+ multiSelectData2);
      }

          private void yourfunction(ArrayList<String> result) {
              for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
                  Toast.makeText(StackActivity.this, result.get(i),
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

          @Override
          protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
              ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
              arrayList.add("st1");
              arrayList.add("st2");
                          // Here put your code
              return arrayList;
          }

      }
  }
  ```

This is a working example, I also include your code in it

Comment: @vikasjagdale you want to pass array `TO` the background function ?

Comment: @ William Kinaan, No I want to pass array list to doInbackground fuction and I'm passing but I'm not getting what I'm passing..

Comment: so `multiSelectData2` is null, you should show us how do u fill it

Comment: Kinnan: I found what exact problem is, I'm making array list null before executing background task.. thank You very much for giving valuable support